# How to put variables inside quotations in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following piece of code,

```
row: {
  '&:nth-of-type()': {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.dark,

  },
```

I wish to put the state variable (this.state.index) inside the braces, however when i try to concatenate with "+"

```
 row: {
  '&:nth-of-type(' + this.state.index + ')': {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.dark,

  },
```

I get a type error saying "Expected 1 argument, but got 2", are there any ideas how i could fix or remedy this?

The block of code is using the material UI library (Customized tables), I am pretty sure it's just my syntax that is wrong, and I'm not quite sure why

Reference: https://material-ui.com/demos/tables/

```
const styles = (theme: Theme) =>
createStyles({
root: {
  height: 500,
  width: '100%',
  marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
  overflowX: 'auto',
},
table: {
  minWidth: 700,
},
row: {
  '&:nth-of-type()': {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.dark,

  },
},
});
```

Comment: This isn't enough. Is there a way you can make a small repo? Or at least edit your question with which libraries are you using?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: I have tried the expression interpolation and get the same problem :/

Comment: Have you tried using square brackets? `var rowStyle = "&:nth-of-type(' + this.state.index + ')'`, then `row: { [rowStyle]: { backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF" } }`

Comment: I am unable to create the var inside the function scope, so i made the rowStyle a state instead with `rowStyle:'&:nth-of-type(' + this.state.index + ')` however, when i use it : `[this.state.rowStyle]` i get a type error 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it has a type annotation

Answer (score 0):

```
const styleObj = {
  root: {
    height: 500,
    width: "100%",
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    overflowX: "auto"
  },
  table: {
    minWidth: 700
  },
  row: {}
};

styleObj.row['&:nth-of-type(' + this.state.index + ')'] = {
  backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.dark
};

const styles = (theme: Theme) => createStyles(styleObj);
```